# Integration of a function in a manifold

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $u$ be a smooth function. Suppose there is a constant $K>0$ such that $$\int_{B_r(p)}(K+u)dV=0, \ \forall 0\leq r<\infty,$$where $B_r(p)$ is the ball with center $p\in M$ and radius $r$.
From the above inequality can we conclude that $u=K$? Please anyone help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try $M = \mathbb R$ with the standard metric, and $K = 0$?

Comment: No I have not try it. Ok let me try

Comment: Yes for $\mathbb{R}$, the function is $0$.

Comment: No.... $\int_{-r}^r u dx = 0$ for all $r$ does not imply that $u$ is zero

Comment: Sorry I was wrong